# New MD5 generating for the same string

Tags: java, string, hash, java-8, md5

I have written a code to generate a MD5 but unfortunately its generating a new MD5 every time for the same string. Can anyone please help.

Code is like below :

```
public static byte[] getHash(String[] constants)
{
MessageDigest md= MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
StringBuilder toBeHashed=new StringBuidler();
for(String c: constants)
{
toBeHashed.append(c);
}
return md.digest(toBeHashed.toString().getBytes());
}
```

Driver code :

```
byte[] hash=MyClass.getHash(new String[] {"01L488213P9579","2021-31-31"});
```

Can anyone please help and let me know if the code I wrote is correct or not? Is it because of the new String array, I am passing every time ?

Comment: Are you sure you’re passing the same String each time?  Please provide code that shows the issue, so we can reproduce it.  That is, provide a function that calls getHash, and gives different output for the same String.

Comment: yes I am using the same string, my String is "01L488213P95792021-31-31"

Comment: Again, please attach the code that shows the problem, the full input and the full output.

Comment: Hi added the code, pls check now..

Comment: SO how to createmd5 hash for the string array ? I am just printing  hash in my driver code, its coming like B@12.. something , new everytime

Comment: Your code won't compile there is typo in `StringBuidler`. Post the actual code that doesn't work for you, your current example after fixing typo works and generates the same hash.

Comment: Okay, you're still only hashing one string once.  And no output that i can see?

Comment: B@12 is not a hash.  That's the address of the byte array.  You can't just do System.out.println(bytearray), because it's not a String.  It just calls [].toString which defaults to an internal representation of the byte array.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki code is compling fine, I just wrote it manually here, cant copy paste the actual code..

Comment: @Max, Ohh right you are, actually I want to see the hash which is created.. how to do it then? I need to save the MD5 hash as a KEY in HashMap, so pls guide me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here, when you say:

> printing hash in my driver code, its coming like B@12.. something , new everytime

You are printing the array object which uses `toString()` method which for arrays shows the object hash code. It is unique for every array object so each time you get a new value.

You have to print the array content e.g. using [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(hash));
```

Comment: This might be useful: [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)